# PHP: 2D array create index or add if exists

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Ok, long story short: I am trying to place items in an array sorted by a value as part of an object(the object defined as $aProductOrdered and the public value:productMan). The post will be variable depending on items added and removed from a database so it has to be dynamic.

For example if the index is 12 for a certain productMan value all items with that would be in one row like:

```
[12][0]:prodObj [12][1]:prodObj
[15][0]:prodObj 
[22][0]:prodObj [22][1]:prodObj
```

where the first is the prodMan value from the object and the second is an arbitrary auto assigned index to loop through representing each object.

Below is what I have but when I go to insert into the array, it accurately says the index I am trying to add to is undefined. How may I add the index if it doesn't exist or if it does just append to it?

```
$vendOrderArray = array(array());

//here we will loop through all non blank posted orders and create objects to place them in our $orderArray
foreach($_POST as $prodID=>$numOrderded)
{
    if(is_numeric($numOrderded) && $numOrderded != "" && $numOrderded != "0")
    {
    $aProductOrdered = getProduct($prodId);
    $aProductOrdered->numberOrdered = $numOrderded;
    array_push($vendOrderArray[$aProductOrdered->productMan],$aProductOrdered);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!isset($vendOrderArray[$aProductOrdered->productMan]))
    $vendOrderArray[$aProductOrdered->productMan] = array();
```

Just before the `array_push` call.

Comment: Ah Perfect, After the commend that was deleted, I had done else  $vendOrderArray[$aProductOrdered->productMan][0] = $aProductOrdered; but your method is better. Thanks! I'm not sure why I didn't think of using isset.